# How to run two curl command sequentially in python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ec2, token

Hi I'm a budding programmer and been trying to run the below curl command in a python environment but keep getting errors - unsure of how the curl command is run sequentially. How can i fix this please !
'''
TOKEN=`curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600"` 
&& curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document
'''
I need to run the curl request inside the instance to get metadata JSON output.

- firstly I will need to run the PUT request curl command to get the token and the value will be stored in the "TOKEN" variable.
- secondly i will run the get metadata curl command which uses the token created.

My code looks like this
'''

```
from .shell import run_command_str
import json

@staticmethod
def get_instance_metadata():

CMD = "TOKEN=curl -s -X PUT http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token -H X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds:21600" && "curl -s -H X-aws-ec2-metadata-token:$TOKEN http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document"
output = run_command_str(command=CMD, shell_command=True)
print("session token: ", output)
if not output:
  AwsClient.logger.info("ERROR: {}".format(error))
  raise Exception("Unable to get the AWS instance metadata : {}".format(error))
AwsClient.logger.info("Instance metadata : {}".format(output))
try:
   output = json.loads(output)
except Exception as error:
   AwsClient.logger.info("ERROR: {}".format(error))
   raise Exception("Error while decoding instance metadata: {}".format(error))
return output.
```

The output i get is :

session token:  ('', '/bin/sh: 1: -s: not found\n')
Traceback (most recent call last):
output = json.loads(output)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/**init**.py", line 341, in loads
raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not tuple

Comment: You should really use `requests` instead of running shell commands.

Comment: And if you must run commands https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html is your friend.

Comment: @luk2302 - Thanks ! will explore the requests module.